# Complex functions and limit calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I would like to know how to calculate limit when $z\to\infty$ of the following complex (!) function:

$$\frac{z^2}{(3z+1)^2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Set $z=r e^{i\theta}$ and take $r$ to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\frac{z^2}{(3z+1)^2}=\frac1{\left(3+\frac1z\right)^2}$$